# Creating a class for creating, checking and inserting keys, values to dictionary based on specified path

Tags: python

I am planning to create a class where it will take 3 different functions; add, insert and check.

1. 'Add' will add keys and values to the dictionary
2. 'Insert' will load the specified path within the dictionary, then insert the keys and values to the dictionary
3. 'Check' will check the keys and values for the dictionary and print it out based on specified path.

My code:

```
class my_dictionary(dict): 

    # __init__ function 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.dict = dict() 

    def insert(self, path, key, value):
        if path is dict:
            print(self.dict, 'dict')
            self.dictpath[key] = value
        else:
            print(self.dict[path], 'else')
            self.dictpath = dict()
            self.dictpath[key] = value

    # Function to add key:value 
    def add(self, key, value): 
        self.dict[key] = value 

    #ToDo check_keys

# Main Function 
dict_obj = my_dictionary()
```

My testing on above codes:

```
dict_obj.add(1, 'name')
dict_obj.insert(1, 'check', 'test')
```

until the second line, i received errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-c4712e1a707f> in <module>
----> 1 dict_obj.insert(1, 'check', 'test')

<ipython-input-80-8c6a8fad0d83> in insert(self, path, key, value)
     12             print(self.dict[path], 'else')
     13             self.dict[path] = dict()
---> 14             self.dictpath[key] = value
     15 
     16     # Function to add key:value

AttributeError: 'my_dictionary' object has no attribute 'dictpath'
```

I am wondering how to approach my desired below output:

```
{1:['name', {'check':'test'}] }
```

Comment: why do you expect `self.dictpath` to exist? did you mean `self.dict`?

Comment: In general, provide the full traceback, always. The error message is perfectly clear though, instances of your class has no `dictpath` property.

Comment: because to access a dictionary key is by using dictionary[key] and to assign it is by using dictionary[key] = value, and if to insert it then must be dictionary[path][key] =value. So my self.dict is dictionary and path is the path, so by using self.dictpath will  == dictionary[path][key]. My approach is wrong so i wish to get some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This code produce your desire dict:

```
class my_dictionary(dict): 

    # __init__ function 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.d = dict() 

    def insert(self, path, key, value):
        if self.d[path]:
            # print(self.d, 'dict')
            self.d[path] = self.d[path]+[{key:value}]

    # Function to add key:value 
    def add(self, key, value): 
        self.d[key] = [value] 

    #ToDo check_keys

# Main Function 
dict_obj = my_dictionary()  
dict_obj.add(1, "name")
dict_obj.insert(1, 'check', 'test')
print(dict_obj.d)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['name', {'check': 'test'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand that insert part but if you want to add another value to the key, maybe you should use as value array. If you want to insert something, just append to the array.

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = dict()

    def add(self, key, value):
        self.dict[key] = [value]

    def insert(self, key, value):
        if key in self.dict.keys():
            self.dict[key].append(value)

my_dict = MyDict()
my_dict.add(1, 'name')
print(my_dict.dict)
my_dict.insert(1, {'check':'test'})
print(my_dict.dict)
```